# Unexpected results with GLSL when using 1D texture buffers

Tags: opengl, glsl

In the following test program, I am trying to render a green square (250 x 250) in the bottom left corner of the screen (500 x 500).

I am using two buffer textures to pass in two int arrays (each array is of size 500 * 500) to the fragment shader.  The arrays are simply populated with x (first array) and y (second array) values that correspond to all the (x, y) coordinates in screen space (this is shown in the init() part of the code below).

In the fragment shader, if the current fragment location (in screen space) is less than 250.0 in both the x and the y directions, that fragment is colored green.  Otherwise, it is colored red.  **Images shown below.**

Below is the full OpenGL code, along with the pass-through vertex shader (located in the main program) and a fragment shader (read in from a file).  In the fragment shader, there are three tests (A, B, and C). **Tests B and C are not working as expected.  They draw the green square on the bottom right instead of the bottom left.**

**Test A (correct):** The output of this code works as expected (a green square in bottom left corner of screen) when I use gl_FragCoord.xy in the conditional if check.

**Test B (incorrect):** If I use the buffer textures along with texelFetch to retrieve the x and y values of the current fragment and then use that in the conditional if check, the green square gets drawn in the lower right hand corner.

**Test C (incorrect):** If I forego the buffer textures and instead just compute the current fragment index and use a simple mod and division to to get the x, y indices, the green square is still drawn on the bottom right.

Any insight would be appreciated.

I'm using:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, 64 bit
glGetString(GL_VERSION) = 4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.113
```

**Main Program: mytest.cc**

```
// This program was modified from:
// https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/173917-samplerBuffer-example-needed

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

static const char Vertex_src[] =
  "void main(void)               \n"
  "{                             \n"
  "  gl_Position = ftransform(); \n"
  "}                             \n";

std::string readFile(const char *filePath)
{
    std::string content;
    std::ifstream fileStream(filePath, std::ios::in);

    if(!fileStream.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read file " << filePath << ". File does not exist." << std::endl;
        return "";
    }

    std::string line = "";
    while(!fileStream.eof()) {
        std::getline(fileStream, line);
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }

    fileStream.close();
    return content;
}

void keybd ( unsigned char, int, int )
{
  exit ( 0 ) ;
}


void reshape(int wid, int ht)
{
  glViewport(0, 0, wid, ht);
}

void showGLerror ()
{
  GLenum err ;

  while ( (err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR )
    fprintf ( stderr, "OpenGL Error: %s\n", gluErrorString ( err ) )  ;
}

void display ( void )
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw a full screen quad.
    GLfloat s = 1.0;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(s,    0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(s,    s,    0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, s,    0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glPopAttrib();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

  glutSwapBuffers   () ;
  glutPostRedisplay () ;
}

void showShaderInfo ( const char *what, GLuint handle )
{
  int len = 0 ;

  glGetObjectParameterivARB ( handle, GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB, &len ) ;

  if ( len > 0 )
  {
    int trueLen ;
    char *s = new char [ len ] ;

    glGetInfoLogARB ( handle, len, &trueLen, s ) ;

    if ( trueLen > 0 && s [ 0 ] != '\0' )
      fprintf ( stderr, "%s:\n%s\n", what, s ) ;

    delete [] s ;
  }
}

GLuint compileShader ( const char *src, GLenum type )
{
  const char *type_str = type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment";

  GLuint handle = glCreateShader( type ) ;

  glShaderSource ( handle, 1, &src, 0 ) ;
  glCompileShader( handle ) ;

  GLint compiled ;
  glGetShaderiv( handle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled ) ;

  if ( !compiled )
  {
    showShaderInfo ( type_str, handle ) ;
    fprintf ( stderr, "Failed to compile %s shader.\n", type_str );
    exit ( 1 ) ;
  }

  return handle ;
}

GLuint linkShaders ( GLuint vsHandle, GLuint fsHandle )
{
  GLint  linked ;
  GLuint handle = glCreateProgram() ;

  glAttachShader            ( handle, vsHandle ) ;
  glAttachShader            ( handle, fsHandle ) ;
  glLinkProgram             ( handle ) ;
  glGetProgramiv            ( handle, GL_LINK_STATUS, & linked ) ;

  if ( !linked )
  {
    showShaderInfo ( "Linking", handle ) ;
    fprintf ( stderr, "Failed to link shader program.\n" ) ;
    exit ( 1 ) ;
  }

  return handle ;
}

void init()
{
  int arraySize = 500 * 500;
  int *array_x = new int[arraySize];
  int *array_y = new int[arraySize];

  // Populate arrays.
  for (int y = 0; y < 500; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
          array_x[(y * 500) + x] = x;
          array_y[(y * 500) + x] = y;
      }
  }

  const size_t  size = sizeof( int ) * arraySize;

  //// array_x
  //
  // Generate and fill buffer object
  GLuint buffer;
  glGenBuffers   ( 1, &buffer );
  glBindBuffer   ( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, buffer );
  glBufferData   ( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, size, array_x, GL_STATIC_DRAW );  // Alloc & Fill

  // Generate texture "wrapper" around buffer object
  GLuint tex;
  glGenTextures  ( 1, &tex );
  glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture  ( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tex );
  glTexBuffer    ( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_R32I, buffer );

  //// array_y
  //
  // Generate and fill buffer object
  GLuint buffer2;
  glGenBuffers   ( 1, &buffer2 );
  glBindBuffer   ( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, buffer2 );
  glBufferData   ( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, size, array_y, GL_STATIC_DRAW );  // Alloc & Fill

  // Generate texture "wrapper" around buffer object
  GLuint tex2;
  glGenTextures  ( 1, &tex2 );
  glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
  glBindTexture  ( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tex2 );
  glTexBuffer    ( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_R32I, buffer2 );
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
  // Init GL context
  glutInit            ( &argc, argv ) ;
  glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE ) ;
  glutInitWindowSize  ( 500, 500 ) ;
  glutCreateWindow    ( "Shader Test" ) ;
  glutDisplayFunc     ( display  ) ;
  glutKeyboardFunc    ( keybd    ) ;
  glutReshapeFunc     ( reshape  ) ;

  // Create buffer object and its texture buffer object wrapper
  init();

  // Load and compile shaders
  printf( "Compiling vertex shader...\n" );
  GLuint vsHandle = compileShader ( Vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER  );
  printf( "Compiling fragment shader...\n" );
  GLuint fsHandle = compileShader ( (readFile("mytest.glsl")).c_str(), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  // Link shaders
  printf( "Linking...\n" );
  GLuint handle   = linkShaders ( vsHandle, fsHandle ) ;

  // Activate shader
  glUseProgram( handle ) ;

  // Populate uniform
  //   (buffer texture will be on TEXUNIT 0)
  glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation( handle, "tex" ), 0 );

  //   (buffer2 texture will be on TEXUNIT 1)
  glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation( handle, "tex2" ), 1 );

  // Draw with shader
  glutMainLoop () ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

**Fragment Shader: mytest.glsl**

```
#version 130                           
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4: enable  

uniform isamplerBuffer tex;
uniform isamplerBuffer tex2;

void main(void)
{
  int width = 500;

  // Get the current screen index we are going to work on.
  // (Used for TEST B and TEST C below.)
  int index = int((gl_FragCoord.y * float(width)) + gl_FragCoord.x);

  // TEST A: This works as expected.
  /*if (gl_FragCoord.x < 250.0 && gl_FragCoord.y < 250.0) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
  else {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }*/

  // TEST B: Use buffer textures to get the value of the arrays at
  // the index computed above.  This does not work as expected.
  int x_i = int(texelFetch(tex, index).r);
  int y_i = int(texelFetch(tex2, index).r);
  if (x_i < 250 && y_i < 250) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
  else {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }

  // TEST C: Get the x, y screen space coordinates based on the index
  // computed above.  This does not work as expected.
  /*int x_i = index % 500;
  int y_i = index / 500;
  if (x_i < 250 && y_i < 250) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
  else {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }*/
}
```

**Result of Test A**
[Test A http://www.shilpigupta.com/stack/TestA.png](http://www.shilpigupta.com/stack/TestA.png)

**Result of Test B and Test C**
(Also notice the green line artifact at the top right of the image.)
[Test B and Test C http://www.shilpigupta.com/stack/TestB.png](http://www.shilpigupta.com/stack/TestB.png)

Comment: It will be useful, if you attach images to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is how you calculate the index:

```
int index = int((gl_FragCoord.y * float(width)) + gl_FragCoord.x);
```

This code will only work if the fractional part of `gl_FragCoord` is zero. Note that OpenGL's window space is defined in such a way that pixel centers lie at half-integer positions ("at comma 5"). Without mutlisampling or other fancy settings, the fragment shader will be invoked exactly for pixel centers, so all of your `gl_FragCoord` values are at .5, which basically results in the shift in 0.5 * width pixels you are observing. (In the case B and C, the green area actually isn't a square, because one line in height is missing at the top, because you already start the bottom line at x_i=250).

The correct approach is

```
int index = int(gl_FragCoord.y) * width + int(gl_FragCoord.x);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Taking into account the window space's native pixel center location fixed the problem and now yield the expected results!